# How to store %3a or %a in String in golang?

Tags: string, go, urlencode

I am new to Go lang and trying to store %3a or %a in String using

`str := fmt.Sprintf("dsfsd%a")`

But when I try to print it, I am seeing "dsfsd%!a(Missing)".

Is there a way to store a sequence of characters like "%a" "%3a" etc.. in String? This string is coming from JSON and it's not hardcoded.

Comment: Use simple assignment to store a string literal in a string variable: `str := "dsfsd%a"`.  There's no need to call fmt.Sprintf as shown in the question's example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is [`fmt.Sprintf`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Sprintf) is treating it as format string

To solve this we can add format string to [`fmt.Sprintf`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Sprintf) and pass value as data to format string

```golang
str := fmt.Sprintf("%s", "dsfsd%a")
```

Here working [example](https://play.golang.org/p/epYqn0-dZO8)

Answer (score 3):

You need to [escape the percent](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#hdr-Printing)

```
str := fmt.Sprintf("dsfsd%%a")
```

Comment: Also, you don't need to use `Sprintf` here if you aren't doing interpolation...